# JavaScript RegExp and Join pattern generation

Tags: javascript, regex

We have a simple JS based input text cleanup to extract specific tokens using regExp. which have the format `<CHAR>-<NUMBER>`. the example code for the same is below. tying to extend this to support the format `<CHAR>/<NUMBER>` or . please let me know how this can be added to the existing formula or better ideas are welcome.

example: Token of the format MR/56743 or MR56743 should be included as well.

the way the script works is: input anything to the text box and on defoucs it automatically cleansup the non matcing content to just have the matched tokens as comma seperated values.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var supported = ['ABCDE', 'XZY', 'IR'].sort();
        var pattern = new RegExp(supported.join("-\\d+|") + "-\\d+", "gi");

        function filter(raw_input) {
            var raw_text = document.getElementById("raw_text").value;
            document.getElementById("raw_text").value = raw_text.match(pattern);
        }
    </script>
    <div id="content" style="width:800px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left">
        Input the scramble for cleanup: </br>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80" name="samplebox" id="raw_text" onchange="filter()"></textarea>
        </br>
    </div>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try a character class like `var pattern = new RegExp(supported.join("[-/]\\d+|") + "[-/]\\d+", "gi");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Token of the format `MR/56743` or `MR56743` should be included as well.

You have `-` in your regex. It matches one single `-`. If you want to match 1 single character from a set of characters, you need a character class `[...]`. If you want to match it one or zero times, use `?` quantifier after it.

Use

```js
var supported = ['MR', 'ABCDE', 'XZY', 'IR'].sort();
var pattern = new RegExp(supported.join("[-/]?\\d+|") + "[-/]?\\d+", "gi");
//                                       ^^^^^           ^^^^^
function filter(raw_input) {
 var raw_text = document.getElementById("raw_text").value;
 var m = raw_text.match(pattern);
 if (m) {
   document.getElementById("raw_text").value = raw_text.match(pattern).join(" ");
 } else { document.getElementById("raw_text").value = ""; }
}
```

```html
<div id="content" style="width:800px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left">
  Input the scramble for cleanup: </br>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="80" name="samplebox" id="raw_text" onchange="filter()"></textarea></br>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew, "[-/]?" did the trick. I was always contemplatoing on [-/] but could not figure out how to include the condition of either of them missing. so ? did the trick.